# Functional component not registered as a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to use Materials `useStyle` in my TypeScript React app but I'm running into an weird issue.

```
// index.tsx

import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  qwe: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});

const init = async () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const Root = () => (
    <div className={classes.qwe}>asd</div>
  );

  render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
};

init();
```

When I run the app I get the message:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

The hook I'm calling is the `useStyles()`. This hook is in the top level of a functional component  and I'm running the latest version of both React and React-dom:

```
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

Comment: It's _not_ being called at the top level of a function-based component - init returns a promise of undefined, not a React element. Did you mean to call it inside Root, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the react hooks inside react component, NOT pure JavaScript function, the latter will break the [hooks-rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). The return value of react function component must be React element(valid JSX element).

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  qwe: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});

const init = () => {
  const Root = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return <div className={classes.qwe}>asd</div>
  };

  render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
};

init();
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for explaining. I accidentally downvoted your answer on the phone. If you make a small edit somewhere I can change it to an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, i had added a param for to resolve that.
in your const nit = async () , add "{}" inside of , like this.

```
const Init = async ({}) => {
  .....
};
```

and called like

```
<Init />
```